# hibernate-jpamodelgen creates broken java classes

Tags: java, hibernate

My entity class is:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    private String K101;

    public String getK101() {
        return K101;
    }

    public void setK101(String k101) {
        K101 = k101;
    }
}
```

Hibernate generates the following class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(SomeEntity.class)
public abstract class SomeEntity_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<SomeEntity, String> K101;

    public static final String K101 = "K101";

}
```

The generated class cannot be compiled because the field name K101 is duplicated.
It works with hibernate version up to 5.2 but fails starting with version 5.3.
A full example project can be found at https://github.com/torstenwerner/jpamodelgen.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: BTW in Java we do not use "SomeEntity_" such names as in C#. We just write "SomeEntity"

Comment: souldn't you chnage setter to this one? `public void setK101(String k101) {
        this.K101 = k101;
    }`

Comment: Use lowecase on the field name: `@Id
   private String k101;`

Comment: SomeEntity_ is a class generated by hibernate. I do not have invented this name.
Adding "this." to the setter does not change anything. BTW the setter was generated by IntelliJ.

Comment: Making the field name lowercase really solves the problem but that was not needed up to version 5.2 of hibernate. If field names must start lowercase – shouldn't hibernate jpamodel detect and report it instead of generating broken java code?